# Make a column with todays date and date +1 in a series using pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, series

So i would like to make a column name call date
The first entry i would make it today's Date, i.e. 23/07/2019
and the following row to be the date + 1 i.e. 24/07/2019 so on...

This is easily done in Excel but i tried this simple thing in pandas and i just cant figure out how!

I already have a dateframe called df
so to put down todays date is relatively simple.

```
    df.Date = pd.datetime.now().date()
```

But im not sure which function would get me the date+1 in the following rows.
Thanks

Comment: You can use pd.date_range(). ie. `pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2019-05-01","2019-06-01"))` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.date_range` can use `'today'` to set the dates. Normalize then create the Series yourself, otherwise `pandas` thinks the DatetimeIndex should be the Index too.

```
import pandas as pd 

pd.Series(pd.date_range('today', periods=30, freq='D').normalize(),
          name='Date')

0    2019-07-23
1    2019-07-24
...
28   2019-08-20
29   2019-08-21
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

If adding a new column to the DataFrame:

```
df['Date'] = pd.date_range('today', periods=len(df), freq='D').normalize()
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but what if i want this date column to add onto my existing dataframe (need matching the length of my exisiting df?), got an error "Length of values does not match length of index"

Comment: @kit12_31 then `df['Date'] = pd.date_range('today', periods=len(df), freq='D').normalize()`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! enjoy the day :)

Answer (score 2):

`pd.date_range` is what you are looking for. To build a series of 31 days starting from today:

```
today = pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
s = pd.date_range(today, today + pd.Timedelta(days=30), freq='D').to_series()
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but what if i want this date column to add onto my existing dataframe (need matching the length of my exisiting df?), got an error "Length of values does not match length of index"